# Convert numpy uint8 array to string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to covert a numpy uint8 array to string in python

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([98, 111,111,107])
print(arr.view('c')) # I can see the output [b'b' b'' b'o' b'' b'o' b'' b'k' b'']
```

I would like to get `book` ? Any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you're facing is that you *don't* have an array of `UInt8`, you have an array of `Int64`, so when you view it as a character array you get a lot of extraneous data.

If you correct set your `dtype`, you can view this appropriately.

```
arr = np.array([98, 111,111,107], dtype=np.uint8)
arr.view(f'S{arr.shape[0]}')

# array([b'book'], dtype='|S4')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
string_ = [chr(i) for i in arr] # outputs: ['b', 'o', 'o', 'k']
```

Then,

```py
string_ = ''.join(string_) # outputs: 'book'
```